# Eclipse not supporting Apache Tomcat 10

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

[image]
My Eclipse 03 2023 doesn't support Apache tomcat > 9

Any ideas why ?
Thanks

Comment: Not true. See [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=563349) and [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=575089). Is this a fresh Eclipse 2023-03 installation? Otherwise, please tell the exact Eclipse WTP version you have. Also, make sure that your project meets the requirements of Tomcat 10 (Java 8 or higher, etc.).

Comment: I installed the last version from Eclipse website : Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)
Build id: 20230309-1520

Comment: JST Server Adapters 3.2.301.v201410241731 org.eclipse.jst.server_adapters.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform

Comment: I use JDK 11 in my eclipse

Comment: Eclipse Web Tools Platform Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 1.1.2.v201001222130 org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui

Comment: Eclipse Web Tools Platform Eclipse XSL Developer Tools 1.0.0.v200905250058 org.eclipse.wst.xsl

Comment: You have some very, very old feature versions installed (the long qualifier at the end is based on the build date). Make sure https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest is listed and enabled on your Available Software Sites preference page and Check for Updates.